# Cakephp 3.6. after installing SSL I get "Controller class Webroot could not be found"

Tags: cakephp

Before everything was fine, then I added the SSL protocol at my providers cpanel and my site is not working anymore, I get the error:

> [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Webroot could not be found.

Anyone any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Which web server are you using? Apache? nginx?

Comment: Apache (strato.de)

Comment: If I remove SSL all works perfectly